# ArcGIS Javascript API: Adding a shapefile with more than 1000 points

Tags: gis, arcgis, shapefile, arcgis-js-api

I am able to add shapefiles with less than 1000 points by using the ArcGIS Portal REST API as shown in this example:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/portal_addshapefile.html

However, there is a 1000 point maxRecordCount through their service. I have tried setting the maxRecordCount in the publishParameters without any luck. I also thought it may be possible to publish our own service with a raised maxRecordCount, but I am not very experienced in publishing custom scripts and did not know whether there was a toolbox that already provided this functionality.

So my question is, is there a way to use the ArcGIS Portal REST API to return more than 1000 records? If not, what would be the best approach to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have access to their map service or data?  More context to the system design would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When a feature service is published to ArcGIS for Server or ArcGIS Online, the user specifies the **Maximum number of records returned by the server.** So, if you are consuming a layer provided by ESRI, and they maxed it at 1000, I do not think there is any way for you to legitimately return >1000 records.

It is very simple to publish a layer to ArcGIS for Server or ArcGIS Online yourself (if you have a server w/ the application, or an ArcGIS Online account). Publishing your own services gives you the ability to control maximum returns.